# How to inject environment variables through the Git notifyCommit hook?

Tags: git, jenkins

I trigger a Jenkins builds of a multibranch pipeline project by placing the following line in the `hooks/post-receive` script of the Git repository:

`curl --fail 'http://localhost:8080/git/notifyCommit?url=/home/john/git-repos/my-code.git'`

As stated in the [Git plugin's documentation](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin), this notifies Jenkins that the repository has changed, and it's time for a build. However, I now wish to inject environment variables into the build by adding parameters to the URL. For example, like this:

`curl --fail 'http://localhost:8080/git/notifyCommit?url=/home/john/git-repos/my-code.git?param1=val1&param2=val2'`

Unfortunately, the parameters do not appear as environment variables in the build. What is the correct way of providing parameters to a build?

Answer (score 1):

That seems to have been requested and fixed in 2015 with [`JENKINS-27902`](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27902).

But...

> This capability was added in git plugin 2.4.0 then was removed in **git plugin 2.5.0 because it introduces a security bug documented in [SECURITY-275](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/commit/5b57aac795991933adbb969abd7c3775cea4e14e)**.
>
> Commit [f0b2d0d](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/commit/f0b2d0d16826906d5743722ae97967bf1d6303d7) allowed the `git/notifyCommit?url=<repo>` to pass additional
>   arguments as name value pairs.  It then places those arguments into the
>   environment of the job being launched.
>
> That allows an unauthenticated user to invoke a job with environment
>   variable names and values which they include in the notifyCommit URL.
>
> They could modify `PATH` or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or other vital environment
>   variables for a job without authentication, whether or not the job
>   required any parameters.

[JENKINS-51999](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-51999) shows that *not* passing parameters is the norm.

> I recommend seeking a better way to pass those parameters (authenticated webhook, ...)

Comment: I cannot use the authenticated webhook (`http://server/job/myjob/buildWithParameters?PARAMETER=Value`) because I'm using a multibranch pipeline project. Suppose I have just created a new git branch, I would not be able to trigger the build of the new branch through the authenticated webhook simply because the Jenkins job doesn't yet exist.

Comment: Why didn't they change the plugin to allow a configured/able whitelist of environment variables?

Comment: @jthill Good question. All I see in https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/commit/5b57aac795991933adbb969abd7c3775cea4e14e is "Users who need that behavior
can configure their Jenkins server to allow the behavior by passing
`-Dhudson.plugins.git.GitStatus.allowNotifyCommitParameters=true` on the
Jenkins command line."